# Build an engine that burns tholins

Tags: engine-design, lander, titan

My idea is to send an hypothetical lander/rover to Titan, and recover from this some samples of rocks...
To create a very efficient engine, I suppose to carry only liquid oxygen, and burn the atmospheric tholins.
Do you think it's possible?

Comment: Keep in mind that the mixture ratios oxidizer:fuel when burning hydrocarbons are usually over 2:1, the oxidizer is the most massive component.

Comment: Also, why use something which is only present in traces, when you have lots of methane in the atmosphere?

Comment: @oefe Because due to the density of methane, is present only in low atmosphere: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Titan#/media/File:Titan%27s_atmosphere.svg   
0 - 30 km methane    
30 - 44 km ethane   
44 - 310+ km tholins

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tholins encompass a large range of hydrocarbon compounds, could be anything from heavy oil-like substances to something more akin to plastics. So it'll burn, the question is if you can use it in an engine. Heavy oil needs a large engine, plastics aren't really usable.

There are two ways around this: either burn the tholins directly and build a steam engine (or e.g. a Stirling engine), or crack the tholins into lighter compounds and burn those. Cracking needs a much larger installation than a steam engine.